# How can I access the FMRadio module by WinRT with Metro style app on Win8

Tags: windows, windows-runtime

I want to implement a metro style app with FMRadio on ARM platform but I'm 
not clear which WinRT API I can use.(My FMRadio is an onboard module not a dongle.)

On windows phone, there has one class called "FMRadio class" and it is as a controller for the device radio.

Does the WinRT support the FMRadio like "FMRadio class" on windows phone?

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be an API tailored specifically for radio and it is hard to tell without a compatible device that has one and no version of Windows 8 that runs on ARM available at this time, but perhaps these articles contain some generic APIs that could be used for that in the future?
[Windows.Media.Devices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.devices.aspx), [DeviceInformation.Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.properties.aspx), [Windows.Devices.Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br225459.aspx).

Comment: Hi Filip Skakun: 
Thank for your help.